# How to transfer java Ajax Answer to my foreach loop

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

**AJAX**

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#selSclCatg').change(function () {
                var catId = $('#selSclCatg').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'CreateProCatFiltServlet',
                    data: {datastr: catId},
                    success: function (pRotyp)
                    {
                        successmessage = 'Data was succesfully captured';
                        $("#successmessage").text(successmessage);
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        alert('Error: ' + e.message);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

How to transfer `function (pRotyp)` to `foreach` loop

```
             <p>
                <label for="SelSclName">Select Scale:</label>
                <select name="SelSclName" id="SelSclName">
                    <option>Select Scale </option>
                    <c:forEach items="${pRotyp}" var="at">    
                        <option value="${at.protypid}">${at.protypnam}</option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>
            </p>
```

Comment: What you are trying here is to get 'javascript' variable(pRotyp) in 'jstl'. This is not possible as jstl and java are server side technology and 'javascript is clientside technology. You can iterate the javascript element inside the javascript function.

Comment: protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        RequestDispatcher rd = null;
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
pntcatId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("datastr"));
            List<ProMasOutEntity> pmoeList = (List<ProMasOutEntity>) new ProductMasteroutput().getProData(pntcatId);
            request.setAttribute("pRotyp", pmoeList);
response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }          
    }

Comment: I agree pikrut's answer, if your want to solve this problem, you can use jquery to rerender the SelSclName node.

Comment: can you give me a example..Pls...

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem.
Firstly, your CreateProCatFiltServlet need return json data. You need to return the "pRotyp" data;

Then, your can change your `function (pRotyp)` as follows:

```
function (pRotyp){
var a =""
for(i=0;i<pRotyp.length;i++){
a+= "<option value="+pRotyp[i].protypid +">"+pRotyp[i].protypnam+"</option>";
}
$("#SelSclName").html(a);
}
```

I don't know more jquery grammer. So you need change the code.

Comment: Thankx for help I'll try with this